# Error in Application_ItemSend using .To when sending an invitation: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to block emails from being sent to a certain group.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim prompt As String
    Dim GROUP1 As String
    Dim GROUP2 As String

    GROUP1 = "GROUP of People"
    GROUP2 = "personx@yahoo.com"

    If InStr(Item.To, GROUP1) > 0 Or InStr(Item.To, GROUP2) Then
        prompt = "This Email is sent to the wrong person/Groups in .To"
        MsgBox (prompt)
        Cancel = True
    End If

    If InStr(Item.CC, GROUP1) > 0 Or InStr(Item.CC, GROUP2) Then
        prompt = "This Email is sent to the wrong person/Groups in .Cc"
        MsgBox (prompt)
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This brings me an error when I want to send an invitation through the Outlook calendar.

> Error number: 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Error on line: `If InStr(Item.To, GROUP1) > 0 Or InStr(Item.To, GROUP2) Then`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not trying to be a smart ass but did you check if Item obj is valid when error occurs?

Comment: First of all, split the line so you can detect what statement is giving the error.
Also add Debug.Print(Item.To) before the line GROUP1 = ...
Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself means that the property `.To` is not valid for `Item` when sending an invitation.

This is because when sending an invitation, the `Object` used for `Item` is an `olAppointmentItem` (which is different than `olMailItem` used when sending an email).

If you still want to check the recipients of the invitation, you should use the property `.Recipients` instead of `.To`.
In any case, you might protect your code by checking the type of `Item` at runtime:

```
If TypeName(Item) = "your desired type" Then
    'your code to check the recipients here
End If
```

If you have different codes depending on the type of `Item`, you might use a switch:

```
Select Case TypeName(Item)
    Case "Outlook.MailItem":
        'check .To
    Case "Outlook.AppointmentItem":
        'check .Recipients
   'etc.
End Select
```

In order to retrieve the exact types, I suggest you set a breakpoint into your code and then use the immediate window to print `Debug.Print TypeName(Item)` over your different use cases. Please note that with the `Select` solution you can also use the `Case Else` statement (where you will fall if any of the previous `Case` was met) where you would just raise an "unhandled exception" or whatever else you'd like to do when you don't know how to treat that specified object type.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Matteo NNZ, the `Cancel` parameter must be declared `ByRef`:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
```